# Tkinter, Display list elements in GUI grid

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, grid

**Edit:** Solved

I'm trying to make 2048 game, the game is separated into 2 modules. One with the rules in it and the other is made in tkinter.
My list is inside the module with the rules in it. So I'd like to know if there's anyway to display the numbers inside my list on my tkinter grid. [This is how it looks like now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boAcw.png) I succeeded to fill the area where the numbers spawn but I don't know how to display them. Thanks for the help.

[This is what I'm trying to get. (picture edited)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMhUi.png)

That's the function to create the grid.

```
def init(n):
    base=[2,4]
    creation= grid(n, 0) #create grid with value 0
    ran1, ran2= base[randrange(0,2)], base[randrange(0,2)]
    addrandom(creation,ran1) ##spawn either a 2 or a 4
    addrandom(creation,ran2) ##spawn either a 2 or a 4
    return creation
```

The result would look like this.

```
  0      2      2      0
  0      0      0      0
  0      0      0      0
  0      0      0      0
```

And the Tkinter looks like this:

```
def drawg_grid(g):     
    can.delete(ALL) #can is the canvas
    for i in range(n+1):
        can.create_line(x0+c*i, y0,x0+c*i,y0 + n*c,fill="#92877d")
        can.create_line(x0, y0+c*i,x0+n*c ,y0+c*i,fill="#92877d")

def square(g):   
     for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            x=g[i][j]
            if x!=0:
                can.create_rectangle(x0 +c*j+2,y0+c*i+2,x0 +c*(j+1)-2,y0+c*(i+1)-2, fill= dico_couleurs_case.get(x), outline= dico_couleurs_case.get(x)) #premade dictionary to get the background color
```

Comment: Just import the numbers from the file? Show the code here directly as text.

Comment: I'll edit my post, hold on a second.

Comment: I edited it, I'd more than happy to explain if there's anything unclear.

Comment: Are you saying you want to access the numbers that `init` returns?

Comment: Yeah, I want them to be shown inside the colored squares, as shown in the picture.

Comment: Where are you calling `init`?

Comment: There's a (new game) button in the code. It has `g= init(6)` in it.

Comment: Then presumably `g` holds the numbers. The game code that calls in it is in the tkinter file?

Comment: Yeah it's `g= [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0], [4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]` this for example. It is yes

Comment: ? Then there you go? That was your question wasn't it? How to access g?

Comment: No, I want to show it inside the grid. Right now it only shows the box but not the number. I'll edit my post and add another picture to show you what I'm trying to get.

Comment: I added the image.

Comment: Never mind, solved it.

Comment: Sorry, was eating breakfast and kind of forgot about this question.

Comment: No worries man ^^

Answer (score 1):

If anybody is wondering, that's what I did.

```
def square(g):   
     for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
            x=g[i][j]
            if x!=0:
                can.create_rectangle(x0 +c*j+2,y0+c*i+2,x0 +c*(j+1)-2,y0+c*(i+1)-2, fill= dico_couleurs_case.get(x), outline= dico_couleurs_case.get(x))
                can.create_text((x0 +c*j+38,y0+c*i+38), text= x, font=("Ubuntu",28,"bold"), fill= dico_couleurs_chiffre.get(x))
```